# Runtime error linking Tensorflow libraries in Xcode

Tags: xcode

My question is about setting up @rpath in Xcode.

I built standalone Tensorflow 2 libraries for C/C++ so as to use them with Xcode 10 running on OSX 10.4.5. In Xcode, I setup Header Search Paths, Library Search Paths, and Runpath Search Paths to where the created lib and include directories are. Also added the created libraries to Link Binary With Libraries. The test program builds fine, but gives a runtime error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libtensorflow_cc.so.1

I used the [MacDependency](https://github.com/kwin/macdependency/) tool to check out the libtensorflow_cc.so library, and it highlights the same issue:

> ERROR: Couldn't open file '@rpath/libtensorflow_framework.1.dylib'.

I then investigated what @rpath has by running this at the command line:

```
otool -l libtensorflow_framework.so
```

And got the following:

```
cmd LC_ID_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name @rpath/libtensorflow_framework.so.1 (offset 24)

cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 32
         path @loader_path/ (offset 12)
```

The LC_RPATH appears to suggest that @rpath is empty (??).

I found several suggestions to use install_name_tool at command line to modify @rpath. But I want to do this with Xcode *only* if possible, as it does not make sense not to be able to do that frankly.

So my question is two parts:

1. Why is runtime @rpath apparently not set properly when setting  Runpath Search Paths in Xcode? Are they different, and if so then how/why?
2. Is it possible to have a correct runtime rpath setting somewhere in Xcode and avoid the use of install_name_tool?

I found a [similar question that was self-answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45456353/xcode-does-not-set-runpath-search-paths-to-binary?rq=1) but did not work for me as in Xcode already my Runpath Search Paths definitions include Debug and Release.